# PHP Class Variable Access

Tags: php

Seems like a simple enough question, so my apologies for asking. As a precursor I'm not necessarily 'new', but rather not so well-versed in PHP.

I have a class, declared as follows:

```
class User
{
    public $id = "";

    public function User()
    {
        $this->$id = isset($_COOKIE['userid']) ? $_COOKIE['userid'] : 0;
    }
}
```

Which seems simple enough, however - upon construction, I get the following set of errors:

```
Notice: Undefined variable: id in D:\xampp\htdocs\sitecore\include\classes.php on line 13

Fatal error: Cannot access empty property in D:\xampp\htdocs\sitecore\include\classes.php on line 13
```

Sorry for asking something so simple. The line in question starts with "$this->$id".

Answer (score 9):

Remove the $ symbol at the 'id' place:

```
$this->id = isset($_COOKIE['userid']) ? $_COOKIE['userid'] : 0;
```

Comment: Much appreciated. Hate being a rookie.

Comment: No worry, we all need help sometimes :)